# Looping through specific set of files from the list

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder with lots of files in this order:

```
A1.txt A2.txt A3.txt A4.txt
```

I don't want my loop to go over all of them but only those on the list:

```
list=("A1" "A3")

for fn in path/${list[@]};
do
  echo "$fn"
done
```

When I do it, instead of getting:

```
path/A1
path/A2
```

I get:

```
A1
A1
```

Without a full path before it.. Can someone help?

Best,

AV

Comment: I would have expected `path/${list[@]}` to expand to the two items: `path/A1` and `A3`

Answer (score 1):

As @steeldriver said, you should get `path/A1` and `A3`. Not sure why you are getting that output.
Instead of using `path/${list[@]};` you could append a prefix to each element of the array like this:

```bash
${list[@]/#/path/}
```

So your for would become:

```bash
for fn in "${list[@]/#/path/}";
do
  echo "$fn"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The array expansion doesn't work in that way.

You could just change where you are introducing the `path/` part.

```
list=("A1" "A3")

for fn in "${list[@]}" ; do
  echo "path/$fn"
done
```